# What else can cause PC clock delay, if CMOS battery and RTC module seems OK?

Tags: clock, cmos

I have a Acer Veriton N260G Series PC nettop with motherbord labelled as [`All In One Motherboard GN40S01-1.0-KSH GN40S01`](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MB-VA309-002-Acer-Veriton-N260G-All-In-One-Motherboard-GN40S01-1-0-KSH-GN40S01-/350785966427)  or [`All In One Motherboard MB.VA309.002`](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I5NC10G). Computer's clocks is getting very late during normal run (approx. 90% as it "counts" only 2-3 hours per 24 "real" hours).

I have replaced BIOS's battery, but it brought no effect. I have checked both batteries voltage only to get 3,24 V reading, which -- as I was told -- is a correct voltage and means, that battery is not near its end-of-life. Right after checking, I have sent this PC to service and just got it back after two weeks of "electronic examination" with an information, that no hardware or electronic failure was found. BIOS, CMOS battery and RTC module are fine and computer operates normally. Yet, BIOS clock still gets late.

What else, except failing CMOS battery or Real-Time Clock module can be a cause for PC's clock getting late?

Comment: Nothing, a low battery can only cause the RTC to stop completely. The RTC works on a crystal, it either works and is accurate (less inaccurate than 1 minute a day would be my guess) or it simply does not work. This behavior sounds to me like a broken RTC. And oh BTW, repair questions are of topic here !

Comment: Unless of course you're moving at near light speeds ;-) Seriously though, I've had problems with a locked-down time server and the OS using an innacurate time to set the BIOS clock. Might be worth asking on superuser.

Comment: What OS? Does it lose time when turned off or when turned on?

Comment: Software can affect your BIOS clock.  First diagnostic suggestion: Boot to a different OS for a day or two and see if the clock behaves the same way.

Comment: If the motherboard was under heavy impact then a RTC cyrstal can be broken, other explanation is that certain program constantly updates new time in RTC. You can use some OS running from USB and compare.